# Laravel 5 validation regex for exact string match

Tags: regex, laravel-5, laravel-validation

I want to add a validation rule for a String to exactly match on any of the Strings provided in a regex pattern. For example, `status` must be exactly 'Approved' or 'Pending' and nothing else.

```
'status' => 'required|regex:[???]'
```

Comment: It seems you forgot to include a question in your question.

Comment: I have tried this but its not working 'status' => 'required|regex:[Approved|Pending]'

Comment: I want status value to be only 'Approved' or 'Pending'

Comment: Still not really a question, but you should have included that from the beginning.

Comment: Please tell me whats missing ?

Comment: Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just use the `in` validation rule.

> `in:foo,bar,...`
>
> The field under validation must be included in the given list of values.

In your case that would be:

```
'status' => 'required|in:Approved,Pending'
```